# How to migrate question about an obsolete OS?

Tags: support, migration

I had flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733045/what-are-the-differences-between-running-a-c-sharp-application-on-windowsnt-and/49733046#49733046) for moderator attention and requested it to be migrated to Super User a few weeks ago. The Q&A-style question was closed as off-topic. Is there anything I can do to migrate the question and answer to superuser.com?

Comment: I'd look into [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) as a destination instead. Look carefully at the existing questions and its help center, maybe your question could fit there.

Comment: My close vote was based on interpreting the question as "how do I install .NET 1.1 on Windows NT4 SP6", even though the title ("What are the differences between running a C# application on WindowsNT and on Windows7") pretty much doesn't fit that at all (*that* question, if we didn't look at the contents at all, would be an obvious "too broad" no matter how you slice it). That's a scenario the majority of us are not going to run into any time soon, but it looked like something Server Fault (not Super User) would handle -- but I could be wrong, since I'm not a Server Fault regular.

Comment: This is a self-answered question. You can migrate it yourself by deleting it and reposting it on another site if you think it's a better fit elsewhere. There's no need to involve a moderator in things you can do for yourself.

Comment: @BilltheLizard:   Sure, but they shouldn't be doing that...

Comment: @Makoto No, in this specific case they shouldn't.

Answer (score 11):

**In General**

There was a PC Magazine article written a few years ago, [If It Ain't Broke, Don't Fix It: Ancient Computers in Use Today](https://www.pcworld.com/article/249951/computers/if-it-aint-broke-dont-fix-it-ancient-computers-in-use-today.html), the has some anecdotes about "old" systems that are still in active use.

Just because *you* aren't using a particular system anymore, or that the original developer has chosen not to support it, doesn't mean that there are no engineers working on those systems. Some government systems are old, but still perfectly usable and must be maintained. Some embedded systems would be too costly to upgrade, or simply don't have the hardware to run newer systems, so you stick with what works. A lot of older manufacturing equipment has onboard computers running "ancient" versions of Windows or Unix, but the equipment is still perfectly useful and has a lot of life left in it.

So, as long as the question is on-topic, closing it simply because the technology "*hasn't been really discussed or supported since the turn of the century*" isn't a good reason to close it.

---

**This specific question is on-topic, but not well researched. It's a duplicate.**

.NET 1.1 is a programming framework. If questions about errors installing Node.js, Python, git or even VS Code are on-topic (they are), then this question is also on-topic. It does not, however, show much research effort. A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=.net+framework+1.1+supported+os) uncovered [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198873/os-compatibility-for-various-net-framework-versions) as the first result, which clearly lists all supported .NET 1.1 operating systems... and Windows NT is not on that list. (*Note: As has been pointed out elsewhere, support for .NET 1.1 was added to Windows NT 4.0 in Service Pack 6a*) But, at the end of the day, it *is* on-topic and should not have been closed. Downvote it if you want to (as poorly researched), close it as a duplicate (it is one), but [A Close Vote is not a Super-Downvote. Please don't use it as one](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one)!

Answer (score 7):

The question has to be on-topic on Super User for it to actually have a home there, but I'm not entirely sure I'm convinced that the question is *that* good to begin with.  I'm fairly *certain* that your question is also *off* topic there, too.

You're talking about Windows NT, an operating system that hasn't been really discussed or supported since the turn of the century.  That *alone* doesn't make your question off-topic or poor, but...I'm not entirely sure what you're asking outside of, "Why doesn't my code work on an old version of Windows?"

Mentally I'm in a bind. I have no clue why you would want to run this code on an old version of Windows.  Super User wouldn't have anything to do with this code either since they don't actually discuss code, they discuss actual software and applications for the everyday computer user.

Put another way... I personally wouldn't cast a close vote on this question - having to support Windows NT must be a new purgatory for developers worse than VB or PHP - but I don't see myself in a hurry to cast a reopen vote *either*, since I'm just not that sure what it is you're really *asking*.

You may think you're asking, "how do I get this to work", but that comes with baggage; getting code to work on an unsupported OS may lead others to believe that this approach is safe and valid, when it *probably* isn't.

At this point I'm more or less rambling.  I don't see any real issue with your question, but I'm not sold on it needing to be reopened, and I ***certainly*** don't want to see it migrated anywhere.

Comment: I think the question should be closed and deleted. .NET 1.1 *is* officially supported under Windows NT 4.0, just not under SP6, but SP6**a**. The "hack" solution is totally unnecessary. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26

Comment: ...What makes the question so blatantly offensive and actively harmful to the site that it needs to be *deleted* @Adrian?

Comment: @Makoto: How to install Windows features is clearly off-topic.  Even if someone writes code that doesn't work unless those features are enabled first.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with that assertion @BenVoigt.

Comment: @Makoto: The "reductio ad absurdum" example is Windows itself.  There's a huge amount of Win32 code out there, and a huge number of Windows programmers, and none of their code runs without installing Windows first.  But installing Windows is off-topic.  It's not a task exclusive to development.  Neither is installing .NET exclusive to development.  Tons of end-users install .NET, and .NET patches, in order to run the software they buy.